# how to make array of object using an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one array

```
var ar=['aa','cc','po']
```

I want to push objects in new array after checking the value of given array .In other words

I have these given conditions

```
var ar=['aa','cc','po']

var arr =[{name:"po"},{name:'aa'},{name:'cc'}];
```

**Expected Output in new Array**

```
  [{name:'aa'},{name:'cc'},{name:"po"}]
```

As `"aa"` in in `0` index then I added object whose name property `aa`.

I try like this .but I used two for look .is there any simple way to do this

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/us055kgw/)

```
var newArr=[];
for(var i=0;i<ar.length ;i++){
   var text =ar[i];
   for(var j=0;j<arr.length ;j++){
    var obj =arr[j];
    console.log(obj.name);
     /*if(obj.name===text){
       newArr.push(obj);
     }*/
    }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: `ar` and `arr`? That's not confusing at all...

Answer (score 4):

This is a proposal in two part, first build an object with the reference to the items of `arr` and the create a new array with the given items of `ar`.

```js
var ar = ['aa', 'cc', 'po'],
    arr = [{ name: "po" }, { name: 'aa' }, { name: 'cc' }],
    object = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.name] = a;
});

ar.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a] && result.push(object[a]);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** iterator and generate object reference based on name and then generate result array using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var ar = ['aa', 'cc', 'po']

var arr = [{
  name: "po"
}, {
  name: 'aa'
}, {
  name: 'cc'
}];

var ref = {};

// generating object reference with name property
arr.forEach(function(v) {
  ref[v.name] = v;
});

// generating result array 
// or you can use forEach as @NinaScholz answer
var res = ar.map(function(v) {
  return ref[v];
}).filter(function(v) { // use filter to avoid null values , in case of missing elements
  return v != null;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @parnav this array may be this `['po' ,'cc','aa']` not sure it is not formatted way

Comment: is there any way to do in lodash

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function convert(source) {

  var 
    obj = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < source.length; ++i) {

    obj.push({name: source[i]});
  }

  return obj;
}

convert(['aa', 'bb', 'cc']); // [{name:'aa'},{name:'bb'},{name:'cc'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you want to assign values from array in sequence:

```
var ar=['aa','cc','po']

var arr =[{name:"po"},{name:'aa'},{name:'cc'}];

arr.map(function(obj,key){
    obj.name = ar[key];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
var ar = ['aa', 'cc', 'po']
var arr = [{  name: "po"}, {  name: 'aa'}, {  name: 'cc'}];
$.each(ar, function(i, v) {
  arr[i].name = v;
});
console.log(arr)
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9vjgmc94/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=['a','b','c'];
var arrayObj=[];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 var obj={};
 obj.name=array[i];
 arrayObj.push(obj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayObj));
```

Output:
  [{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one very functional way of doing this job with no more than an assignment line. However Anoop Joshi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36998072/4543207) is more elegant provided that the `ar` array is shorter than equal to in length to the `arr` array.

```js
var arr = ['aa','cc','po'],
     ar = [{name:"po"},{name:'aa'},{name:'cc'}],
    res = arr.map(e => ar[ar.findIndex(f => f.name == e)]);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res) + "</pre>");
```